# How is it possible to preview a link under the subject when an email is viewed in the inbox?

Tags: php, email, hyperlink, gmail

Some days ago I subscribed a firefox account to sync my add-ons, bookmarks, etc. Mozilla sent an activation email for me with a ***verify email*** link which was visible under its description without need to opening the email.
Would you learn me how to send such a link with my email? Code in php language is preferred.
Thank you

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a One Click Confirm Action. This is the declaration:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Verification",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://myexpenses.com/approve?expenseId=abc123"
    }
  },
  "description": "Confirm Your E.D subscription."
}
</script>
```

You also need to be validated by google first:

1. use this tool to validate your schema and send it to special google email address:
     [markup-tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/)
2. Fill out the "Gmail Schema Whitelist Request" form:
     [Gmail Schema Whitelist Request](http://Fill%20out%20the%20%22Gmail%20Schema%20Whitelist%20Request%22%20form)

Good Luck